# Google Analytics tracking code

Tags: google-analytics

The website example.com has different Google Analytics tracking codes. 
One we installed in the agency UA-XXXXXXXX-1 and another one the webmaster installed  UA-XXXXXXXX-3 property tag that monitors our traffic at the agency and one roll up property tag for all the 115 agencies UA-XXXXXXXX-15. ( for the main website www.example2.com)

I read installing multiple instances of the Google Analytics Tracking code on a single web page, especially different versions of the code, is not a supported implementation.

I don't have the script knowledge to know it this correct the way it is installed right now. I would appreciate your help who can read this script.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a correct implementation - not only are all of the instances of the tracker the same, current version of GA, they also make correct use of [named trackers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#naming_trackers) that send to different GA properties.

The tracker name is what is set as "name" in the configuration object ( the thing in curly brackets) on tracker creation:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', {'name':'trackerName'})
```

The separate tracking ids (UA-XXXXXXX-1, UA-XXXXXXX-2 etc) make sure that there is no double counting (since the hits go to different properties) while the tracker name makes sure that the different tracker instances do not overwrite each other an can be [configured and called separately](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#running_commands_for_a_specific_trackers).

Answer (score 0):

Code looks ok, but you should check it using [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk)

It will probably complain about a non-standard implementation, but you should see if the three pageview requests are being made.